# How to connect fridge to existing water line

Tags: plumbing, water, refrigerator

Received a new fridge and it looks like it has the same adapter end as my existing water line. What's the best method for connecting the two?

[image]

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Unscrew the male-male coupling from your existing water line and the line from the fridge should then screw right in:
[image]

Comment: That did the trick.

Comment: @grephappiness Welcome! When someone posts a quality answer that answers your question, you can click the checkmark next to the answer to mark it as "Accepted" to signify that you question has been successfully answered.  Thanks, and again, welcome!

Comment: Had both line ends actually been male, a female-female coupling would've been the answer. Typically these supply lines use 3/8" fittings, but ymmv.

Comment: @end-anti-semitic-hate thank you! I was looking for how to accept the answer before but did not see the checkmark.

Comment: @grephappiness You're most welcome.  That was my guess.  It's certainly not obvious to many new community members, so you're in good company!